# React Router - Read URL

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am trying to implement an invite system. A user will get an email with an invite link:

```
http://foo.com/accept?invitation=XXXXX&orgName=House%20of%20Grue
```

Basically, I need to pull the orgName out of the URL so I can use it as a variable on the page where they finalize their signup and I need to direct them to the correct page, foo.com/invite.

My route for this is:

```
const routes = <Route component={App}>
    <Route path="/invite" component={Invite} />
</Route>;
```

Do I need to do anything different in my routes for when they click the link from their email?

I read that this.props.location.pathname will get me the URL and then I can slice it up from there. Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.props.location.query` will give you an object whose key/value pairs are the query parameters.

For your example, `this.props.location.query` would provide you with;

```
{
    invitation: 'XXXXXX',
    orgName: 'House of Grue'
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I also changed my Route path to be "/accept" instead of "/invite". Everything after the "?" was captured by React Router. Super convenient. Thanks again!